# Does eclipse has a native method to update an IModule added to an IServer when the project has been renamed?

Tags: java, eclipse, rename, project, rcp

I have a project which has been added and it is running in an IServer,
I would like to rename the project from the workspace and also in the IServer however when it is running it is facing the problem that the resource cannot be modified because it is being used, when the module is stopped the rename success but the IServer fails because the project the IModule is linked to doesn't exist anymore.

My first approach was through an `IResourceChangeListener`, just before the eclipse rename the project, 
I was trying to stop and remove the application running in the IServer in order to the renaming 
of the project perform successfully, but continue failing aparently because some process was using some file(s) of the project.
and the rename job triggered not finish due to same exceptions.

`Problems occurred while refreshing local changes`
`org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Errors occurred while refreshing resources with the local file system.`
`org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException(null)[380]: java.lang.Exception: The resource tree is locked for modifications.`

I tried with all the types of events, mainly with the `PRE_DELETE` and `PRE_BUILD` but the exceptions remains.

Comment: What is `IModule` and `IServer`, these aren't part of core Eclipse

Comment: I mean the interface for create a new server runtime: [IServer](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/api/org/eclipse/wst/server/core/IServer.html)

Comment: If you want to do something on a rename you write a 'rename participant' using the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants` extension point. Lots of info in the Eclipse Help.

Comment: @greg-449 Do you know if that extension point could work with any kind of project in the workspace or only with Java projects? I did some attempts and that was my perception

Comment: The rename participants extension point is not specific to Java, it is used for all renames.